# Links aren't clickable after using parallax scrolling

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I've been making this website for school and I thought i'd figure out how parallax scrolling works. So i've started with the simpelest tutorial to be precise this [one](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/). After doing this I placed my navigation bar in. I remember this worked fine at the time but after working allot on the responsiveness I didn't check back and now I can't click on the links anymore.
This is my html:

```
            <div id="group2" class="parallax_group">
            <!-- <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer-back">
                                                                                                background
            </div> -->
            <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer-base">
                <div id="nav" class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">Over ons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wat leveren wij?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Demo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="section group">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam id nam, necessitatibus at odit nobis vitae, dolor sequi sunt doloremque minima, debitis. Sed debitis possimus esse soluta mollitia est culpa.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="middle" class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui autem impedit, a, error accusantium soluta molestias quidem quo totam beatae eligendi sint, modi voluptatem nemo fugiat recusandae ullam consequatur nihil?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident voluptatibus, quaerat nostrum ullam distinctio praesentium! Nemo eveniet provident id, tenetur cumque natus, quas porro possimus maiores, minus amet laboriosam ea?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is my css:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
}
h1{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
p{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
header {
    z-index: 5;
    line-height: 100vh;
}
header .parallax_layer-back {
    background: url(sample.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#group2 {
    z-index: 3;
}
#group2 .parallax_layer-base {
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
.parallax {
    perspective: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax_layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.parallax_layer-base {
    transform: translateZ(0px);
    z-index: 4;
}
.parallax_layer-back {
    transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    z-index: 3;
    height: 150vh;
}
.parallax_layer-deep{
    transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
.parallax_group {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /*transform: translate3d(700px, 0, -800px) rotateY(30deg);*/
}
/*Columns*/

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.2%;
}
#middle{
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-left: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

/*navigation*/

.nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 30;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    line-height: 0;
    z-index: 30;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    z-index: 30;

}
a:link {
    color: #2F649B;
    font-family: inherit;
}
a:visited {
    color: #2F649B;
}
a:hover {
    color: #6D92B9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #26507C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
footer {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100px !important;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I know it's allot of code but I have no idea what it could be so i went and gone ahead and gave you everything.
edit: The other html parallax group:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Squirel WebDesign</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="handheld.css" media="screen and   (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (max-width: 480px)">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parallax">
            <header class="parallax_group">
                <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer-base">
                    <h1>i'm a bloody big header preferably with a squirel</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer-back">
                </div>
                <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer-deep">
                </div>
            </header>
```

Comment: They work fine for me...Try changing the z-indexes, you have all three set to 30, try 30,31,32

Comment: That didn't seem to work too :/ maybe my mistake is in the other parallax group would you mind to look at that one too?

Comment: don't mind, paste it up

Comment: The css and the html is now completely up there

Comment: The new bit of html shouldn't change much, You're 2nd link tag may need checking as it looks like double declaration. Can't help much more as it works for me and I can't see anything obvious wrong. Have you tried different browsers ?

Comment: #### EDIT top link isn't double, Maybe my vision is though, Wakey wakey ME

Comment: I put your code into a fiddle and it appears to be working fine, though likely missing some styling. http://jsfiddle.net/5j31fh2c/  Perhaps try to repro your issue in a fiddle or codepen so we can see what's not working?

Comment: it almost has to be something to do with the z-indexes cause if i make the site 480px width and it changes to the responsive website they links work like they are suppose to

Comment: add the z-indexes in the handheld css and take a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5j31fh2c/ this is all the html and all the css in a jsfiddle sorry for not posting that earlier i'm kinda new to this kinda help

Comment: @billy where should i add z-indexes? also i don't see why this would make a change since it only overwrites the main.css

Comment: so they work in hand held for you. yes? in the jsfiddle they work for me.

Comment: I figured it out, the banner / first parallax group was to big so it overlapped the nav and that nav was in a parallax group that had a lower z-index so i fixed the height of that first parallax group now it is fixed thanks for all your help guys!!!!